# Directory.Move not working properly for UNC paths

Tags: c#, .net, io

I want to move a directory to a new location, then I use the `Directory.Move` API, but it does not work for the UNC path, e.g.

`Directory.Move(@"\\Server1\Path1", @"\\Server1\Path2");`

It will throw below exception

> [System.IO.IOException] = {"Source and destination path must have
>   identical roots. Move will not work across volumes."}

And I did not find any wordings tell this API not work for UNC path from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx). So which API works for the UNC path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't MOVE if they are on different volumes.  MOVE is a file system operation that changes where it lives without copying it.  To move across different volumes, you would have to copy it, then delete the old one.

It has nothing to do with UNC.  Moving from C:\something to D:\something would error the same way and for the same reason.

Comment: "\\Server1\Path1" and "\\Server1\Path2" should be in the same volume, but different directories, right?

Comment: @CarlosLiu Path1 & Path2 is the share name on Server1.  "\\Server\Share\Path1" to "\\Server\Share\Path2" is different folders at the same share.

Comment: @BlackFrog Thanks for the explanations. Directory.Move(@"\\Server\Share\Path1", @"\\Server\Share\Path2") will work